# flutter build ios error after add OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension to Podfile

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode10.3

I used onesignal_flutter https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter

in my flutter project

and after follow this steps to setup onsignal sdk for ios in this link

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

I run this two commands in visual studio code terminal

`flutter clean` and `flutter build ios`

I get this error

```
Running pod install...                                              2.7s

Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            4.8s

Failed to build iOS app

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:
↳

```
  ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application
    extensions:
    /Users/jaadara/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.framework/
    Flutter
    ld: warning: linking against a dylib which is not safe for use in application
    extensions:
    /Users/jaadara/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.framework/
    Flutter
    /Users/jaadara/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webview_plugin
    -0.3.8/ios/Classes/FlutterWebviewPlugin.m:19:55: error: 'sharedApplication' is
    unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions
    where appropriate instead.
        UIViewController *viewController = [UIApplication
        sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
                                                          ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jaadara/Desktop/cicr_finals/ios/Pods/Target
    Support Files/flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iP
    honeOS11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:110:54:
    note: property 'sharedApplication' is declared unavailable here
    @property(class, nonatomic, readonly) UIApplication *sharedApplication
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("Use view controller based solutions where appropriate
    instead.");
                                                         ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iP
    honeOS11.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:110:54:
    note: 'sharedApplication' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    /Users/jaadara/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webview_plugin
    -0.3.8/ios/Classes/FlutterWebviewPlugin.m:286:24: warning: comparison of distinct
    pointer types ('NSString *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
      if (_invalidUrlRegex != [NSNull null] && urlString != nil) {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.

Encountered error while building for device.
```

and this my Podfile code

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

any help please

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, I not understand 100% yet, but I believe that docs wasn't easy to understand, and a little outdated. I make all things two times and won't work, same erros...
I have to add add this line, without that, given anther error.

```
use_frameworks!
```

Try something like that:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
  target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```